# Slick slider not working despite no errors and correct paths to CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am completely puzzled here. I have seen many questions about the Slick slider but none of the solutions worked for me.

I followed steps from Github - I installed Slick via npm and am using Gulp to process my CSS/JS files, which compiles my Slick script from node_modules. **I checked the source script and styles and the Slick code is definitely being compiled correctly and after jQuery.**

This is my head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
     <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title><?= $page['title'] ?></title>

        <?php
        include SITE_DIR . '/parts/script.php';
        include SITE_DIR . '/parts/style.php';
        ?>
     </head>

     <body>
```

My mini-slide.php file:

```
<div class="mini-slider__items">
        <div class="mini-slider__item">
            <img class="tiles__image" src="/images/logos/Logo.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="mini-slider__item">
            <img class="tiles__image" src="/images/logos/Logo.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="mini-slider__item">
            <img class="tiles__image" src="/images/logos/Logo.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="mini-slider__item">
            <img class="tiles__image" src="/images/logos/Logo.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="mini-slider__item">
            <img class="tiles__image" src="/images/logos/Logo.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="mini-slider__item">
            <img class="tiles__image" src="/images/logos/Logo.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="mini-slider__item">
            <img class="tiles__image" src="/images/logos/Logo.png" alt="">
        </div>

    </div>
```

And my mini-slider.js:

```
$('.mini-slider__items').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 700,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    arrows:false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
 });
```

What I have tried:

- checked that jQuery is loaded before Slick
- checked that mini-slider.js file is compiled into the main source file and in the correct order
- console - no errors displayed

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated, I am getting very frustrated now :(

Comment: If you don't get errors, the only reason I can think of is that your javascript code is not called at all. Did u try to **console.log** anything just before and after the `slick()` call to see if that line is actually reached/executed?

Comment: Hi @cheesyMan thanks, yeah I did which was executed just fine, but having read your comment I tried selecting the slider container and clg it, which returned null. 

Worth noting is that I am using someone else's starter files and the script was originally put in the head (and is currently still there).

The null makes me think the script is being executed before html is generated but I'm not sure. I wrapped it in document.ready and the result was the same. Adding it right before the closing <body> tag also did not help.

Comment: I'm afraid it's difficult to say anything without your exact environment and scripts. I've tried a static code with your html markup and your Slick initialization code and everything works perfectly.

Comment: Hi @cheesyMan you're absolutely right. I seem to have found a solution by pasting the Slick script directly into the body, so it is definitely the environment/the order in which scripts are executed. I'm just going to find a more elegant way to do this now but thank you for the tip to console log as it made me re-do it and eventually find a solution!